# Aligned Hedron Network and Ulamog's Despoiler

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I was to use [Aligned Hedron Network](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aligned%20Hedron%20Network) against an Eldrazi deck to exile big creatures, am I then able to send these creatures to the graveyard with the likes of [Ulamog Despoiler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ulamog%20Despoiler) to give him the 4 +1/+1 counters? I'm not sure if the cards exiled this way can be targeted by these types of abilities...

If this works and my Aligned Hedron Network was to be destroyed afterwards, the creatures would not return from Exile as they were placed in the graveyard, Correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ulamog's Despoiler makes no limitations as to what cards can be moved from exile to graveyard except the cards' owners. Therefore, you can move any of your opponent's exiled cards, no matter how they got exiled. Note, however, the rulings on the Despoiler's Gatherer page regarding face-down exiled cards.

If the Aligned Hedron Network was destroyed after Despoiler has had its effect, the Network's effect would end and return all cards exiled with it to the battlefield. Unless a few specific exceptions apply (which they don't here), effects do not track objects across zones, and the Network would not return the cards put into the graveyard by Despoiler.

Comment: Ah, that's how I envisioned it working. Brilliant. what I forgot is that Aligned Hedron network would also exile my creatures... and that would cause significant problems unless I destroyed it myself afterwards.

Comment: @Nathan: Meh, you have a despoiler, and they have an absence of creatures. You seem ahead to me. What you need is a way to sacrifice the network for value once the despoiler's got his num nums.